# jenkins polling git ssh repository can not trigger builder

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I setup a jenkins server in vmware for my own private project. The Git server (SSH) is in intranet too. I can successfully click "build" button and pull new code and built it. But the "Polling SCM" setting with "H/5 * * * *" or "* * * * *" does not work. It always gives the following message as the following:

Git Polling Log

Started on May 19, 2014 2:29:00 PM
We need to schedule a new build to get a workspace, but deferring 7,794ms in the hope that one will become available soon (all_suitable_nodes_are_offline)
Done. Took 0 ms
No changes

The GitHub type of tirgger may not work for me, since when git push the code, this VMWARE jenkins server is not visible to me due to the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a well-known bug.  This problems defeats the entire purpose of having Jenkins in the first place, but for some reason they just don't get that.  The bug:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22750

Comment: removed /var/lib/jenkins and downgraded to v 1.553, Works fine now. Checked with latest version but did not remove /var/lib/jenkins, did not work. Maybe should remove it.